# Can I use Skype to share my screen with the class during a lecture?

Tags: display, skype

I give a lecture to a class with about 50 students. Some of them sit in the back and do not see the slides very well. To help them, I thought of starting a conference call in Skype, letting them join, and then sharing the screen with the conversation. I used Skype before for screen-sharing with two people. Will it also work for 50 people? Are there any other limitations in using Skype for this purpose, e.g., a time-limit on the conversation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [Skype Website](https://www.skype.com/en/features/group-calls/), you have a limit of 25 people to make a video call. But if you use [Microsoft Teams](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/teamwork/online-meetings?rtc=1), you can make groups for your classes and start video conferences and share files with no cost, and for up to 250 people at the same time. It's really awesome and recommended.
Hope this answers your question.